# Is it okay to let users to reset core data iCloud sync by rebuilding from ubiquitous content?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud

I have a core data app that uses iCloud to sync data across devices (OS X and iOS versions).  Every once in a while a user reports that syncing just sort of stops working, as if the client devices just stop receiving or properly processing updates to the core data database stored in iCloud.

As a solution, I'm thinking about adding something like an option for users to rebuild the data on each device from the data stored in iCloud.

I'm thinking that this will involve calling the persistent store coordinator's migratePersistentStore function, with NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption as one of the options.

Will this work? Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't personally done this in a shipping app, Apple does explain this scenario and state you may need to do this occasionally in real-world usage in the [iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html) (scroll to bottom - see Removing an iCloud-enabled Persistent Store). So yes, you should be able to provide that functionality without issue. And yes, you do use `migratePersistentStore` and pass `NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption` as an option.

Another option is to completely wipe out all iCloud and local data at once, but Apple states specifically that this should not be done in a shipping application.